# Joomla create 2 different sub menus with same menu items

Tags: joomla, menuitem, submenu

I have two menus first one is **"3D"** and second one is **"2D"**.
I have some sub menu items in common,for example Getting Started sub item common in **3D** & **2D**.

But i can't create that menu in same name.But that is very important in our project. How can i create sub menu items with same name?

Comment: You can have the same name for all your menu items if you like, the key is the alias must be unique within each menu group.  Also, @emmanuel's comment is the proper solution if you need your alias' to match as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create two menu items with the same alias but you could link them using:

```
Menu item Type: System Links -> Menu Item Alias
```

This menu item will just be a link to the other item using the same alias.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

In menu manager (I use Isis admin template):

1. Tick submenu you need to duplicate
2. Click batch tab at top of page (a lightbox appears)
3. In the second box down, select where you want the menu item to come under
4. Under this is a copy or move option; select copy
5. Click Process
6. Done

P.S. Depending on how your menu assignment is set up, you may then have to go into module manager to your menu module (in my case CK maximenu), menu assignment tab, and tick the appropriate box so that your main menu appears on the page.