# Joomla 3 Breadcrumb Duplication

Tags: joomla, blogs, categories, breadcrumbs, article

I am creating a new blog section for our site.  Here is the revelant setup information:

Menu: Blog

Menu Item: Blog - links to blog home page article

Category: Blog
            - 6 sub categories

Articles:

Blog home page

Blog posts belonging to those 6 sub categories.

(Please correct my setup if it isn't)

So here's the problem.  On the blog post articles the breadcrumb looks like: Home > Blog > Blog > article title.  That second blog link is linking to /blog/30-blog (30 is the category id of blog).  I have no idea why this is appearing or how to get rid of it.

[image: Screenshot of blog menu]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your menu structure.

Comment: ok added... but like i described its very simple.  There is a blog menu and 1 item linking to the blog home page.

Comment: This item links to an `Articles -> Single Article`. Why don't you convert it to `Articles -> Category Blog`?

Comment: I'm not sure, you tell me why.  This is my first joomla build.  I had it linked to a single article and am doing a template override to customize the layout of this article.  Should I have made it a category blog and done something differently?

Comment: Based on your setup breadcrumbs is correct. Firest "blog" instance is for the menu item and second for the blog category. If you want to make a link to another menu item you have to try a **menu alias**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25849488/3834042 or you have change the menu item type to `Articles -> Category Blog`.